# How set ngClick only for $first element in ngRepeat?

Tags: angularjs

How can ng-click be assigned to the `$first element` in ng-repeat? In the below code `doSomething()` should be called only when the first input is clicked. The remaining inputs shouldn't have ng-click handlers assigned. I've found examples of how to use `$first` with ng-class or ng-show but not with ng-click.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-click="doSomething()"/>{{item.name}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also use [ngSwitch](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angSwitch) which avoids creating all the handlers which you mention in your comment to the accepted answer:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-switch on='$first'>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-switch-when='true' ng-click="doSomething()"/>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-switch-when='false'/>
    {{item.name}}
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is working correctly. The switch seems to be repeating with each div.

Comment: Oops my mistake - included the {{item.name}} in there twice. Now corrected.

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-click="$first && doSomething()"/>{{item.name}}
```

working examlpe: http://jsfiddle.net/wLrYc/

Comment: Yay, for prettier solution :-)

Comment: Thanks, this will work - but I was asking how to avoid creating ng-click handlers for the remaining inputs after $first. Items could be very large which would result in a lot of unnecessary click handlers being created. I believe using this pattern repeatedly through the app could affect performance.

Answer (score 0):

Semi-ugly solution: send $first as argument to doSomething()

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-click="doSomething($first)"/>{{item.name}}
</div>
```

and then have $scope.doSomething(actuallyDoSomething) only do it's thing if actuallyDoSomething is true.